# Prevent debugger from breaking for duration of a specific code block/method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Let me start by saying that I know about the `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute` and I'm using it in a number of places with much success.

However, I'm searching for a complementary solution that would work for my specific scenario, which I'll now illustrate...

Say I have a homegrown data-access framework. This framework comes with lots of unit tests which ensure that all my high-level data-access APIs are working as expected. In these tests, there is often a requirement to first seed some test-specific data to a one-off database, then execute the actual test on that data.

The thing is, I might rely on unit tests not just to give me a passive green/red indication about my code, but also to help me zero in on the source of occasional regression. Given the way I've written the tests, it's easy to imagine that a small subset of them could sometimes give me grief, because the code that performs the test data seeding and actual test code both use the same framework APIs at lower levels.

So for example, if my debugging of a failed test happened to require that I place a breakpoint inside one such common method, debugger would stop there a number of times (maybe an annoyingly large number of times!) before I'd get to the point I'm interested in (the actual test, not the seeding).

Leaving aside the fact that I could theoretically refactor everything and improve decoupling, I'm asking this:

**Is there a general way to quickly and easily disable debugger breaking for a specific code block, including any sub-calls that might be made from that block, when any of the executed lines could have a breakpoint associated?**

The only solution that I'm aware of is to use conditional breakpoints. I would need to set a certain globally accessible flag when entering the method that I wanted to exclude and clear it when exiting. Any conditional breakpoints would then have to require that flag must not be set.

But this seems tedious, because breakpoints are often added, removed, then added again, etc. Given the rudimentary breakpoint management support in Visual Studio this quickly becomes *really* annoying.

Is there another way? Preferably by manipulating the debugger directly or indirectly, similarly to how the `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute` does it for single method scope?

---

**EDIT:**
Here's a contrived example of what I might have:

```
public class MyFramework
{
    public bool TryDoCommonWork(string s)
    {
        // Picture an actual breakpoint here instead of this line.
        // As it is, debugger would stop here 3 times during the seeding
        // phase and then one final time during the test phase.
        Debugger.Break();

        if (s != null)
        {
            // Do the work.
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class MyTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var fw = new MyFramework();

        // Seeding stage of test.
        fw.TryDoCommonWork("1");
        fw.TryDoCommonWork("2");
        fw.TryDoCommonWork("3");

        // Test.
        Assert.IsTrue(fw.TryDoCommonWork("X"));
    }
}
```

What I'm really looking for is something roughly similar to this:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var fw = new MyFramework();

        // Seeding stage of test with no debugger breaking.
        using (Debugger.NoBreakingWhatsoever())
        {
            fw.TryDoCommonWork("1");
            fw.TryDoCommonWork("2");
            fw.TryDoCommonWork("3");
        }

        // Test with normal debugger breaking.
        Assert.IsTrue(fw.TryDoCommonWork("X"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a code sample for your problem?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: I'll try.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the actual test. When it is hit then set the breakpoint on the place you really want. The breakpoint window allow breakpoints to be enabled or disabled. Also, you can place conditions on them such as only effective when a variable has a value.

Comment: On edited question. Add a Boolean, change its value just after `fw.TryDoCommonWork("3");` and set a conditional breakpoint where you want that checks the value.

Comment: @AdrianHHH: I'm using this exact technique when the number of the false stops is known to be too large. Sometimes the time to press F5 10 times is juuust a bit quicker then having to juggle two or three breakpoints and set up their conditions. Any way you put it it's a hassle to jump through these hoops while trying to stay focused on the problem at hand, don't you feel? Repeat 10 times in a row and you're bound to pop a nerve. ;)

Comment: Please re-read both of my earlier comments.

Comment: @AdrianHHH: I have. You're basically suggesting the exact thing I mentioned in my original post when I talked about the conditional breakpoints. While I recognize that it is *a* solution, I'm really asking if there is a *better* one. I'd be perfectly happy with something that would allow me to disable breaking on any breakpoint, present and future, conditional or not, when hit from a given code block that I'm not interested in.